# Spontaneous Shutdowns

Tags: fedora-15

My four year old thinkpad x61 has just started shutting down spontaneously.  I have no idea why, I know it's not thermal related because it's not too hot when it shutsdown and I installed lm-sensors and I can measure how hot it gets.

I recently switched to Fedora 15 (from Ubuntu) about 2 months ago, but this started happening about 10 days ago.

I've looked through /var/log/messages and haven't found anything interesting.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could possibly be your Thinkpad's [motherboard battery (CMOS battery)](http://www.ebay.com/itm/CMOS-Battery-LENOVO-Thinkpad-X60-X61-Tablet-PC-92P1210-/150447092236), given the age of the computer. I do not think this is at all related to your migration to Ubuntu Linux from Fedora 15.

Comment: that seems pretty right on.  I definately wouldn't have thought of that.